# How to create a custom shortcode for custom login form?

Tags: shortcode, login

I am trying to create a shortcode for the login form to use on a page.

I have manage to get a simple form, but am looking to add the "forgot password link"

Here is what I have so far ... any way to add to this to have the form with the forgot link?

```
add_action( 'init', 'onco_add_shortcodes' );

function onco_add_shortcodes() {

    add_shortcode( 'onco-login-form', 'onco_login_form_shortcode' );
}

function onco_login_form_shortcode() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
        return '<p>You are already logged in!</p>';

    return wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the URL for lost password use `wp_lostpassword_url()`

Reference:

- [wp_lostpassword_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_lostpassword_url)

Comment: I saw that reference, but the problem is that it takes the user away from my page with the form on it ... which defeats having the custom page.

Comment: Well you said you want the, and I quote you: "form with the forgot link". You have the form and you want to add a link. The link goes somewhere - which is obvious. So please clarify you needs.

Comment: @MatthewWoodard Any progress on clarifying your needs?